# Grails: How do I make changes to a plugins domain class if the change affects the schema of the domain's table?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I have a plugin used by different projects and I found out that I need to make a change in one domain class. How do I make sure that the schema is properly updated in the projects that depend on my plugin?

Update:

I'm changing `maxSize` constraint of one `String` field from 255 to 8000.

Comment: Set your projects DataSource `dbCreate` to `update` or use database migrations.

Comment: If the other projects have already put data on the domain class you have to write migration script. :-( ppl hate mig scripts. :-)

Comment: This all depends on what you are changing in domain object. For instance,if you are adding a new attribute that is not `nullalbe`, setting DataSource to `update` won't help. What is it you are changing in domain object?

Comment: @Armaiti question updated!

Comment: The update might do the trick here, the other question is if altering table is granted to the datasource credential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I make sure that the schema is properly updated in the projects
>   that depend on my plugin?

You really can't, at least not in a way that is generally applicable.  In general a plugin should not assume that the application is generating or modifying schema.  You should document the change as part of your plugin's upgrade notes.

Comment: Ok Jeff, it's a little difficult to expect plugin users to actually create and run migration scripts though.

Comment: "it's a little difficult to expect plugin users to actually create and run migration scripts though" - Most developers don't have their application configured to generate DDL anyway.  One way or the other the database needs to be kept in sync with the application expectations.  You don't really have a choice but to inform the users.  If you say that your plugin is only usable by folks using the migrations plugin, you are limiting your audience.